# Get Adjacency matrix for Polygons in GeoJSON using R

Tags: r, json, adjacency-matrix

I've got a set of polygons in the GeoJSON file. They're neighborhoods in Boston. I would like to produce an adjacency matrix in CSV format, where element j,j is 1 if district i is adjacent to district j (i.e. they are touching).

I found a code in R on the internet and used for my data set ([Uber Movement Dataset](https://movement.uber.com/explore/boston/travel-times/query?si=1116&ti=&ag=censustracts&dt%5Btpb%5D=ALL_DAY&dt%5Bwd;%5D=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt%5Bdr%5D%5Bsd%5D=2020-03-01&dt%5Bdr%5D%5Bed%5D=2020-03-31&cd=&sa;=&sdn=&lang=en-US)) as folows:

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
polys <- readOGR("D:/boston_taz.json")
adj <- gTouches(polys, byid = TRUE)
```

and got the following error:

```
> library(rgeos)
> library(rgdal)
> polys <- readOGR("D:/boston_taz.json")
OGR data source with driver: GeoJSON 
Source: "D:\boston_taz.json", layer: "boston_taz"
with 2728 features
It has 7 fields
> adj <- gTouches(polys, byid = TRUE)
Error in RGEOSBinPredFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, "rgeos_touches") : 
  rgeos_binpredfunc: comparison failed
```

As I'm new to R, what's the issue and how do I export the resulting matrix to .csv format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a zero-width buffer to clean up the topology problems in R and my problem is solved.

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
polys <- readOGR("D:/boston_taz.json")
polys2  <- gBuffer(polys , byid=TRUE, width=0)

adj <- gTouches(polys2, byid = TRUE, returnDense=TRUE, checkValidity=TRUE)
write.csv(adj ,"adj.csv")
```